# Ionic 6 API REST post method headers

Tags: rest, ionic-framework, post, cors, http-headers

I'm trying to make a API REST Request but I can't connect with the API, I'd trying different options but I could do it.

This is my ts:

```
post(emplead2){
    let data = {
      "LastName": this.LastName
    }
    
    this.proveedor.addStudent(data)
    .subscribe(
      (data)=>{this.empleados = data;},
      (error)=>{console.log(error);}
    )
  }
```

this is my service

```
addStudent(data): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type','application/json');
    const body = 'hola';

  console.log(body)
  console.log(headers)
    return this.http.post('APIURL',body,{headers: headers});

  }
```

This is the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'MYAPIURL' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not from your ionic application or how you are sending the POST request. What is basically happening is that your http request is being blocked by CORS policy for security reasons. You can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) what exactly is CORS policy and why it is blocking your request.

Fixing this depends on the language/framework you built the API with, but what you need to do is allow your ionic application's base url (http://localhost:8100) to access the API and bypass the CORS policy.